# Angular 16 date picker

Tags: angular, date, datepicker

I have a angular application that runs on versions 16.0.0 and i have set of components which has form fill-ins with date inputs.

Earlier i was using ng2-date-picker by vilo(https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker) , but am getting issues like this when i run the application.

```
Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs/plugin/isBetween'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrAfter'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs/plugin/isSameOrBefore'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /Users/harshachinnaswamy/harsha/web-messenger/node_modules/ng2-date-picker/fesm2022/ng2-date-picker.mjs depends on 'dayjs/plugin/isoWeek'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

I have tried using the angular material date picker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker?activeTab=readme) but the problem with this is that I am using tailwind css in my project and the UI does not work properly with the library unless i install all of material UI for the date picker because it uses the UI from it like themes, buttons etc..

I am looking for an alternate date-picker library for angular version 16.
Which should have features like:

1. Disable dates. (min, max)
2. Format dates (mm-dd-yyyy).
3. Date range selection.
4. Change detection, month & year picker selection.

   Someone, please suggest libraries compatible with angular 16 and have the set of features in it.